# Is there a Gmail Drive?

Tags: software-recommendation, mount, cloud, gmail, storage

is there the gdrive in ubuntu? like windows have.
Or similar

Comment: You should realise that google doesn't allow things like gmail drive in their terms of service, which means that your drive may be taken down at any time and without warning. *Don't rely on it*, should you get it to work.

Comment: a gamil drive is in the works for Ubuntu, and for ios. source: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/google-drive-is-coming-to-linux/

Comment: this will help you, http://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available

Answer (score 5):

Why not use **Ubuntu One** for it? Its already integrated in OS.

Answer (score 4):

This was the only thing that I could find: http://richard.jones.name/google-hacks/gmail-filesystem/gmail-filesystem-using.html

It doesn't look that user friendly unfortunately. Good luck getting it to work.

> You can mount your Gmail filesystem
>   either via fstab or on the command
>   line using mount.
>
> To use fstab, create an entry
>   /etc/fstab that looks something like:
>   /usr/local/bin/gmailfs.py
>   /path/of/mount/point gmailfs
>   noauto,username=gmailuser,
>   password=gmailpass, fsname=zOlRRa 
>   Note: If you cut and paste this entry
>   remember to remove the spaces after
>   the commas
>
> The username and password fields speak
>   for themselves. The fsname is the name
>   of this Gmail filesystem. It is
>   important to choose a hard-to-guess
>   name here - because if others can
>   guess the fsname, they can corrupt
>   your Gmail filesystem by injecting
>   spurious messages into your Inbox.
>
> To mount from the command line, do:
>
> mount -t gmailfs
>   /usr/local/bin/gmailfs.py
>   /path/of/mount/point -o
>   username=gmailuser,
>   password=gmailpass, fsname=zOlRRapassword=gmailpass, fsname=zOlRRa

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like dropbox, but as far as i know there is no gdrive in ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [gspace](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=gspace&appver=&platform=) Firefox add-on to use gmail as a online storage place.

You can use 'Google Doc Mount' to mount google-docs as an external drive in nautilus. There is a nice [article at omgubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/edit-work-on-save-your-google-docs-via-nautilus-no-browser-needed/) about Google Doc Mount.

Comment: Dead link. Looks like Mozilla have removed that addon.

Answer (score 3):

Since no one really answered your question, here it goes: it's in the works.

Google has reportedly said to Linux users to [hang tight](http://www.engadget.com/2012/04/25/google-drive-is-coming-to-linux-tells-users-to-hang-tight/), altough this **was** like a month ago.

You can still use Gdrive from the [browser](http://drive.google.com), but the syncing app to install in Ubuntu hasn't been released yet.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you are looking for but, it creates a drive on your system which stores and syncs your google docs with you system. Putting other files in it might also work.

But if you only want to sync your documents then its a great application cause it would create a drive of google docs and you can put your files into it and they will be instantly synced with google docs. Its two way sync

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:doctormo/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install gdocs-mount-gtk

Here is the complete How-To
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/edit-work-on-save-your-google-docs-via-nautilus-no-browser-needed/

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** there is.

See the **Grive tools**, with detailed installation instructions:
http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-google-drive-client-grive-and-grive-tools

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [google-docs-fs](http://code.google.com/p/google-docs-fs/) package, which I've been using, but there are some limitations until the official Linux version is released. ([See tutorial](http://www.dailytut.com/linux/google-drive-ubuntu.html).) Like Gaba said, Google hasn't said anything about the Linux version yet, sadly. Also google-docs-fs is no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 0):

If

- we are looking for a freeware application (if not, there is [Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/plus))
- **non-googledrive solutions are to be accepted as an alternative**
- the idea is to have **at least as much free space as google drive** provides,

there is already [Megasync client for Linux](https://mega.co.nz/#sync).

**50 GB for a free account** and a sync app that, just like Dropbox and GoogleDrive for Windows (and unlike all google drive applications for Linux that I tried, except Insync) is able to make **selective synchronization**.

(That is why I cannot use free google drive apps as alternative. I have stored a lot of files on the online google drive but I do not need all of that on each device.)

For the fanatics of monochrome layouts, there is the downside of a red tray icon.