# Is there a Google Drive client available?

Tags: software-recommendation, google-drive

I'd like to install a [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/start#home) client for Xubuntu (12.04).

I'm getting non-English Google results, and I didn't find [grive](https://github.com/Grive/grive/) in the Xubuntu repositories.

Does anyone know of a client that works well for Ubuntu or it's supported derivates (or installation instructions for grive?)

Comment: If you aren't set on Google drive try Media Fire Express.

Comment: try https://www.insynchq.com/ this works fantastic on Ubuntu.

Comment: This is either a big coincidence or you are the same user as posting the same question an hour ago. http://askubuntu.com/q/320308/88802

Comment: There's not an offical app for Ubuntu. That's why use web version until release for linux :)

Comment: another tool to consider would be google-drive-ocamlfuse http://gdfuse.forge.ocamlcore.org/

Comment: @Mateo Link ? Cause the answers are very messy now and it's hard to find the good answer

Comment: https://github.com/odeke-em/drive/blob/master/platform_packages.md

Comment: oh and guess what - http://www.webupd8.org/2015/05/grive2-grive-fork-with-google-drive.html

Comment: https://www.change.org/p/google-create-a-native-linux-google-drive-application

Comment: not sure why I can't post this as an answer but this has worked much better than gdrive 2 for me: https://github.com/odeke-em/drive

Answer (score 96, accepted):

## For Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.10

**Apparently [grive](http://www.lbreda.com/grive/) exists on a ppa** - I installed it and it works reasonably well. This is preferable in my opinion over the [google-docs-fs](http://www.zimbio.com/Ubuntu+Linux/articles/gVdrI310RS3/Access+Google+Drive+Ubuntu) solution, since that doesn't put your files permanently on your drive, and grive does. Also, grive isn't a commercial venture like InSync - which is described as "free during beta".

The PPA for grive can be found on webupd8's site using these instructions:

[Grive: Open Source Google Drive Client For Linux ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/grive-open-source-google-drive-client.html)

One limitation that the current version of grive has is that it doesn't automatically sync your drive directory. But I found [this blog post describing a script to fix this](http://blog.vel.nu/?p=28) and make grive sync whenever a file in the drive directory is changed.

(This answer is originally based on @uri's comment, which has since disappeared)

EDIT: grive is now officially dead, but [grive2](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/05/grive2-grive-fork-with-google-drive.html) is a fork of the original version with some improvements.

Comment: There's [a new article on webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/grive-update-brings-full-google-drive.html) now with updated information about grive.

Comment: Actually, I've found grive and various others don't correctly handle deletion cases. :'(

Comment: Didnt work for me:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 125, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 84, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (6, "Couldn't resolve host 'launchpad.net'")

Comment: Grive now provides two-way sync...!!!    http://www.lbreda.com/grive/

Comment: To make it automatically sync changes in `~/Drive`, use [this script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6035748/) after running `grive -a` first. Add this script to your Startup Applications to autostart. It uses `inotifywait` to watch for changes in the `Drive` folder. The link in the answer wouldn't work for me

Comment: @minerz029 Thanks for the script! How about modifying it a little so as to check also the remote Drive for any changes, say every five minutes?

Comment: A more up to date solution, install grive-tools from this ppa
https://launchpad.net/~thefanclub/+archive/grive-tools
Or use SyncDrive
http://syncdrive.fr/

Comment: @eyal  how to use grive as only one way sync. like client to server only

Comment: unfortunatelly does not work on 12.04 out of the box a special steps should be done to install it.

Comment: GRIVE was a great tool but it sadly died on 20th April when Google discontinued service for the Google Documents List API version 3.0 API.  https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-google-drive-client-grive-and-grive-tools AND https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/  for more background...

Comment: @SteveEllis it is still working here, I suppose people using Google Apps for Work are getting extended support.

Comment: @badp I've moved to OverGrive by the same developer and haven't looked back.

Answer (score 60):

<sub>This answer contains an answer for all current Ubuntu versions, starting with recent versions at the top.</sub>

## Ubuntu 17.10 and later (GNOME Online Accounts)

Open System Settings and select *Online Accounts* -> under the **Add an account** heading select *Google* and authenticate with your Google password.

[image]

Make sure the "Files" permission is granted:

[image]

Now your Google Drive will appear in the Files application (nautilus), like this:

[image]

---

## Access Google Drive files offline

Google Drive allows you to access some files offline, but on desktop
this feature only works on Google Chrome. If you have the browser, install the [Google Docs Offline](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs-offline/ghbmnnjooekpmoecnnnilnnbdlolhkhi) extension offered by google.com. Return to Google Drive and navigate to gear icon -> *Settings* -> *Offline*, and enable *Create, open and edit your recent Google Docs, Sheets and Slides files while offline*.

---

## Ubuntu 14.04 and later (for all desktop environments)

Open Drive is a Google Drive client for desktops written in Electron.  It's fast, secure and easy to use.

**Features**

- Automatic synchronization between files
- Automatically updates modified files.
- Gives notifications.
- Runs in the system tray.
- No need to spend money.

To install Open Drive in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install odrive-unofficial
```

---

### Ubuntu 16.10 - 17.04 (GNOME Online Accounts)

GNOME 3.18 and newer (in Ubuntu 16.10 and later) has native desktop integration that will let you easily browse, manage, open, upload, and download your files. Just add your Google account in GNOME's online accounts application to get started.

To enable Google drive desktop integration in Ubuntu 16.10-17.04 follow these steps:

1. Install GNOME System Settings and GNOME Online Accounts.

   ```
    sudo apt install gnome-control-center gnome-online-accounts
   ```
2. Launch GNOME Online Accounts.

   ```
    gnome-control-center online-accounts
   ```

   Make sure you close Unity Control Center first. If you have Unity Control Center open and you call `gnome-control-center online-accounts`, then it opens the Unity Control Center window instead of the GNOME one.
3. In the new *Online Accounts* window that opens click the **Add an online account** button, then in the **Add Account** window click the Google icon to add your Google account and authenticate with your Google password. Make sure *Files* is enabled by being toggled to the ON position.

You should now be able to access your Google Drive files from the Files (*nautilus*) app.

The same steps also work in Ubuntu 16.04 if it has GNOME 3.18 or newer installed. The current version of nautilus in Ubuntu 16.04 is nautilus 3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu5.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `grive` isn't by Google.

Comment: GRIVE project is currently suspended after API updates from goole have caused it to stop working. See link below: https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-google-drive-client-grive-and-grive-tools

Comment: I've opted for OCAMLFUSE as a stop-gap but am missing off-line working. I am also holding out for a better solution; maybe even a fully fledged Drive client from Google (as promised a couple of years back)...

Comment: It does not download the Googledocs documents :(

Comment: If you have already installed grive, use `sudo apt-get purge grive` first to clear out the old version.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Just curious: for Ubuntu 16.10 w/ Unity, will installing GNOME control center and gnome-online-accounts package mess up anything with Ubuntu's Online Account manager?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10 already includes GNOME 3.18 for the most part, however because Unity doesn't use GNOME Control Center (also known as GNOME System Settings or just Settings) and GNOME Online Accounts and instead, it ships with a fork (unity-control-center), it doesn't include this feature by default. Even so, you can use the GNOME 3.18 Google Drive integration in Unity as well as other desktop environments, as long as you use Ubuntu (and derivatives: Xubuntu, etc.) 16.04 or later. This won't work with Ubuntu versions older than 16.04

Comment: Make sure you close Unity Control Center first.  If you have Unity Control Centre open and you call `gnome-control-center online-accounts`, then it raises the Unity Control Center Window instead of the Gnome one.

Comment: @karel,  With the 17.10 option, I am wondering if the files are being downloaded or something each time I restart the computer. (I think this was available to 16.x too. ) Is it possible not have it all download each time?

Comment: Please ask this as a separate question, because it's also a topic about using GNOME desktop environment in Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Turned the answer around and upvoted.  Have a look at edit history. **;-)**

Comment: Hey, is there any way I could access my G-Suite Team Drives?

Comment: @Zangar [Sync Google Team Drive With.. (Dropbox, OneDrive, etc.)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V696eB_J7QE) + run this command in the terminal for more information: `snap find nextcloud`

Comment: @karel If I understand the video correctly, that is for individual PDF files. I really need the whole set of team drives available. Is that possible? [How do I install Google's “Drive File Stream”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084732/how-do-i-install-googles-drive-file-stream)

Comment: Is there a way to do Ubuntu 16.10 step 3 via CLI? I mean, authenticate in my google account without using GUI?

Comment: [Using Google Drive from the Linux Command Line](https://linuxnewbieguide.org/using-google-drive-from-the-linux-command-line/)

Comment: [Here](https://sites.google.com/site/installationubuntu/home/ubuntu-16-4-lts/google-drive-in-nautilus) is a great tutorial on doing the same, just explained more thoroughly (for XFCE, too).

Comment: Does this work for Kubuntu as well?
When I add Google the only option in "Use this account for" is Youtube. Obviously, I mostly want Google Drive support.

Comment: @MXMLLN the GNOME features in this answer are just for GNOME, but it might be worth asking a separate question about similar features that are compatible with Kubuntu/KDE/Plasma.

Answer (score 26):

## Unfortunately, Not with an official client. An unofficial driver exists online.

> Note that there is no 12.04 PPA. I've contacted the maintainer asking for one to be made.

There is currently no official Linux client supported by Google.

> For Linux
>
> Google Drive isn't currently available for the Linux operating system. Linux users can still access Google Drive on the web – drive.google.com New Window or through the Google Drive mobile app.

Refer to http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2375082

There is an unofficial Gdrive FS in a PPA:

1. execute `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:invernizzi/google-docs-fs` to add the PPA.
2. once the command finishes, run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-docs-fs` to install GdriveFS. Please be patient as this step may take a while.
3. Create a folder within your home folder called "Drive".
4. Execute: `gmount Drive username@gmail.com`, replacing your username as necessary, to mount your Google Drive. This must be run in a terminal.
   Test show that this application works fine, and is filemanager-independent, being an FS driver.

Comment: OK, gotcha, but then give him the instructions to build grive from git then, man! (upvote given in anticipation of compliance :P)

Comment: @izx I couldn't find Git instructions, but did find a modified Google Docs FS that supports Drive. If you can point out the location of the instructions for Git, I would be happy to add them with credit.

Comment: Seems that PPA is offline or something. I cut & pasted your command-line comments in to a terminal and I'm getting 404s for that one PPA. :(

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on 12.04 right now...

Comment: Installed under 12.04 Precise, work for / google directory, but subdirs are empty. After some copy attempts stops working at all.

Answer (score 20):

Two solutions: Insync, or `google-docs-fs`.

## InSync

OMG! Ubuntu! [posted](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/08/insync-brings-google-drive-to-ubuntu) an article about Google Drive and Ubuntu in 2012 about [Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/).

> - Download the [Insync.tar.gz](https://www.insynchq.com/downloads/linux)
> - Extract to your Home folder
> - Open a new terminal and navigate into the extracted Insync folder using the ‘cd’ > command (e.g. `cd insync/`)
> - Run: `sudo ./insync-installer` Follow any on-screen prompts
>
> After installing there are a few other things to note: After installation
>
> - Insync must be started from the Terminal by running `insync`
> - The app doesn’t auto-start by default, and there is no in-app way to enable > this

**Update:** There is a Ubuntu package from the [Download page](https://www.insynchq.com/downloads/linux) which installs (via software centre by default), configures an update repository, optionally installs file browser integration and starts InSync.

## `google-docs-fs`

This app mounts your drive so you can thread it like a file system. Instructions come from [OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/how-to-access-google-drive-via-nautilus-in-ubuntu).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:invernizzi/google-docs-fs
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-docs-fs
```

Once everything that’s needed has been installed log out and back in.

- Open Nautilus
- Create a new folder in your Home folder titled ‘Drive’
- Open a Terminal and run: -
- gmount Drive username@gmail.com
- Input your password

Your Google Drive is now mounted in the ‘Drive’ folder

Comment: But i think Insync doesn't provide an option to do a selective sync. It syncs all the files in my Google Drive.

Comment: Not yet, but their working on it. See https://www.insynchq.com/

Comment: The second solution doesn't work on 12.04: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/invernizzi/google-docs-fs/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

Comment: insync works just fine. downloaded installer and started app. nice ty.

Comment: omgubuntu also [posted](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/06/google-drive-linux-petition-now-10k-signatures-strong-google-yet-to-respond) a petition for a google supported drive client which is close to full. I Just signed.

Answer (score 14):

**Grive Tools** will allow for easy desktop install of Grive and setup of Google Drive on Ubuntu 12.04 or later.  **NOTE:** This project is no longer supported see **UPDATE: July 2015**

[image: Grive Tools Screenshot]

To install **Grive Tools** from The Fan Club PPA on **Ubuntu 12.10 and 15.04**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thefanclub/grive-tools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grive-tools
```

For **15.10 and later** you can install `grive-tools` package manually:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~thefanclub/+archive/ubuntu/grive-tools/+files/grive-tools_1.15_all.deb
sudo gdebi grive-tools_1.15_all.deb
```

Supported Desktops include Unity, Gnome, KDE, Xfce, Cinnamon and LXDE.

Supported languages : Afrikaans, English, Spanish, Dutch, German, French, Italian, Portuguese, Russian, Serbian, Arabic and Japanese.

For information about the Grive Tools project here : https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-google-drive-client-grive-and-grive-tools

**UPDATE: July 2015**

This project has been replaced by **overGrive** a complete Google Drive desktop client solution for Linux. See :  https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive

Comment: Worked for me, just now. Can't be that out of date.

Comment: GRIVE project is currently suspended after API updates from goole have caused it to stop working. See link below: https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-google-drive-client-grive-and-grive-tools

Answer (score 7):

There is another program, google-drive-ocamlfuse. This is a real Google Drive client (with a directory mounted via fuse, just like the Windows client), also this has automatic syncing and downloads the googgle documents in odf formats.

It seems that a ppa is available too. Here is a how to:

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-mount-google-drive-in-ubuntu-linux-using-google-drive-ocamlfuse.html

The source is here (the install process might not be smooth as there are dependencies and their dependencies, all having to be installed as ocaml packages, and some dont generate config files):

https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse

Comment: Best option. Much better then Grive which doesn't sync.

Comment: I use this on my laptop (16.04 Mate) -- works great, easy to set up, and with the PPA it gets maintenance.  In general use, it's just like having the Dropbox app -- just puts a volume into my file browsing (I shortcut it on my desktop next to my Dropbox).

Answer (score 6):

`Insync` repository is available for Ubuntu now.

Following are the steps to install **Insync**:

1. Add the source to `/etc/apt/sources.list` file 
   (Sample line: `deb http://apt.insynchq.com/[DISTRIBUTION] [CODENAME] non-free`)

   To add the line directly to sources.list file do the following:

   ```
   echo "deb http://apt.insynchq.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/insync.list
   ```
2. Import the key

   ```
   wget -O - https://d2t3ff60b2tol4.cloudfront.net/services@insynchq.com.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install Insync

   ```
   sudo apt-get install insync-beta-ubuntu
   ```

[Source: insynchq.com](https://www.insynchq.com/linux)

Answer (score 5):

### Grive with a GUI = SyncDrive

---

**UPDATE**: According to the latest news from the source of this piece of information cited below, "***SyncDrive support site is closed and it can't pull files, so it won't work.***" Therefore, another alternative such as **overGrive** (formerly called "*Grive Tools*") mentioned in another answer can be recommended instead.

---

**SyncDrive** is front-end cleaned GUI which uses [Grive](https://github.com/Grive/) as base.
There is no official Google-Drive app for Linux at this moment.
**SyncDrive** is designed by David who is the creator of Ubuntu-based MacOSX-look-alike [Pear OS](http://pearlinux.fr/).

**SyncDrive** can be setup easily and synchronize your files stored on your **Google Drive** in your **~/SyncDrive** folder. It can automatically sync files and also shows storage used/remaining. **SyncDrive** also has an indicator for easy access.

[image: SyncDrive Screenshot]

To install **SyncDrive** in Ubuntu; open **Terminal** (Press Ctrl+Alt+T) and enter the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/pear-apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install syncdrive
```

*Source: http://www.noobslab.com/2013/09/syncdrive-google-drive-available-for.html*

**Note:** Files in Google Docs format do not seem to be stored locally.

Comment: Note: this is not an automatic synchronization app, and you have to manually chose "Synchronize now" from the drop-down of the app-indicator. But this's a really useful app for Google Drive synchronizing.

Comment: You can mention, that SyncDrive is not opensourced. At least there is no source code for SyncDrive anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

**You can use [`drive`](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive)**

`drive` is an unofficial Google Drive client originally developed by Burcu Dogan while working on the Google Drive team. It has more features than Grive2 and fewer bugs.

`drive` does [intentionally](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive#why-another-google-drive-client) not support background two-way syncing, but the `drive pull` and `drive push` commands work recursively by default, equivalent to "one-way syncing on demand".

**Installation for Ubuntu**, according to [the documentation](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive/blob/master/platform_packages.md):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:twodopeshaggy/drive
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install drive
```

Answer (score 4):

The official Google Drive app for linux is not yet released. But there are third party options. InSync is a really good option.

Download the Insync.tar.gz from

```
http://s.insynchq.com/builds/insync-linux-beta1-py27.tar.bz2
Extract to your Home folder
Open a new terminal and navigate into the extracted Insync folder using the ‘cd’ command (e.g. cd insync/)
Run: sudo ./insync-installer
Follow any on-screen prompts
```

After installing there are a few other things to note:

```
Insync must be started from the Terminal by running ‘insync’
The app doesn’t auto-start by default, and there is no in-app way to enable this
```

Source : [OMG!UBUNTU!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/08/insync-brings-google-drive-to-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

**Updated on September-20-2015**

Ubuntu 12.04 is NOT officially supported because of dependency issues but [THIS PROJECT IS NO LONGER SUPPORTED DUE TO GOOGLE DRIVE API CHANGES](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/content/how-install-grive-tools-ubuntu-1204-64bit) .So here is installation of "over grive" a new Google Drive client.

Step 1:  [Download the latest version of overGrive DEB here.](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/sites/all/modules/pubdlcnt/pubdlcnt.php?file=https://www.thefanclub.co.za/sites/default/files/public/overgrive/overgrive_3.1.2_all.deb&nid=168)

Step 2: Launch OneGrive from [launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41208/how-to-launch-an-application-in-unity)

Step 3: A window will appear ,click on <kbd>Connect account</kbd> then a  browser window will open for you to `sign in` to your Google account.

Step 4: At the end you will get a **code** ,copy that code and paste it in the Onedrive window at **Account** entry box and click <kbd>validate</kbd>

Step 5: After setting your preferences (like location etc...) click <kbd>Start Sync</kbd>

For Reference [here](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive/installation-instructions-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a command-line-only solution, the best I've found is [rclone](http://rclone.org).  It works with a variety of cloud-based storage solutions, and is fairly easy to script with.  Examples below.

Incrementally backup "/path/to/local folder 1" to "/someremotefolder/folder 1" on Google Drive.  Additional commands can be added to backup additional folders.

```
#!/bin/bash
rclone sync "/path/to/local folder 1" "drive:/someremotefolder/folder 1" -v
```

Restore the remote copy, incrementally overwriting the local copy.

```
#!/bin/bash
rclone sync "drive:/someremotefolder/folder 1" "/path/to/local folder 1"
```

You can also transfer files between different remote folders and cloud storage solutions using the appropriate syntax for those media.  The online documentation and man page are pretty easy to follow.  Don't forget to do the initial setup steps (per the documentation), after installing rclone.

Comment: `rclone` is great, +1

Comment: This the most lightweight, simple yet powerful option to me. And no Google funny stuff in the background.

Answer (score 1):

This won't answer your question completely, but I'll post this anyway in case it helps you or other people.

Also, this answer is only going to be useful if you want the client for the sake of accessing your Documents offline.

If you use Google Chrome, you can get the Google Drive extensions which works offline once you activate it on your account. (There is an "Offline Docs" tab in your Google Docs' left side bar.)

You can get the extension here:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-drive/apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf

I must say, it's rather limited. Documents is the only format that you can view and edit. You will be able to view your Spreadsheets, but not edit them. In my case, those limitations are okay since I mostly only use Documents.

More info:
http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1628467

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`gdrive`](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive), an open source cross-platform command line tool for Google Drive.

Note that this is not the same as [`drive`](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive), which is mentioned in another answer. It's quite similar though: also written in Go, and a comparable feature set, but different command line parameters.

**To install and use:**

1. **[Download](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive#downloads) the binary.** Choose the one that fits your architecture, for example `gdrive-linux-x64`.
2. **Copy it to your path.**

   ```
   sudo cp gdrive-linux-x64 /usr/local/bin/gdrive;
   sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/gdrive;
   ```
3. **To use it for downloading a file:**

   ```
   gdrive download 0B7_OwkDsUIgFWXA1B2FPQfV5S8H
   ```

   Of course, use your own file ID instead of the `0B7_Ow[…]` argument. You find it in the URL when opening your files in the Google Drive web interface, or right-clicking them and clicking "Get sharable link …". In the latter case, remember to turn off link-sharing again if you don't want others to access the file when they get the link.

At first use, the tool will need to obtain access permissions to the Google Drive API. For that, it will show you a link which you have to visit in a browser, and then you will get a verification code to copy&paste back to the tool. The download then starts automatically. There is no progress indicator, but you can observe the progress in a file manager or second terminal.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Zoho Docs](https://www.zoho.com/docs/) that have official client for Linux:
[image: Zoho Docs official image]
[image: zoho client link]
[image: downloading zoho client]
[image: zoho client login screen]
[image: zoho client Ubuntu choose folder]
[image: zoho official client tray ico]
[image: zoho official client Ubuntu Linux - set the bandwidth]
[image: Zoho official client for Ubuntu Linux - select folders for sync]

Works as Google Drive for Windows - just sync your files and you can edit them in web-browser. You can read more at [official help page about sync client](https://www.zoho.com/docs/help/zoho-docs-for-desktop.html).

Comment: Zoho seems to be a Collaboration and Enterprise Resource Management system. How is it related to Google Drive?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I mean https://www.zoho.com/docs/ - it is like Google Drive.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification! In that case I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to install and use the software. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.) Ping me if you want an up-vote on the result.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thank you for pointing me out, I added screenshots - looks pretty informative yes?

Comment: Looks good but I actually meant installation and usage instructions (typically textual, with supporting images if necessary). Random screenshots without description usually aren't very helpful.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is asking about clients for Google Drive, not about alternatives to Google Drive.

Answer (score -2):

You can use nice russian service [Yandex Disk](http://disk.yandex.ru) that have WebDav and free 10 gb and official command-line sync client. Also inside you can create and edit documents from Microsoft Office Online.

[image: yandex disk web, google drive analog]

Comment: This does not answer the question.