# How to access Google drive from Ubuntu

Tags: sync, google-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Google Drive client available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available-for-ubuntu)

Is there any app that can fully integrate with Ubuntu(with Nautilus) to access Google docs and other files that I have stored on my google drive?

Is it possible to do a selective sync from GDrive to Ubuntu?