# Is it possible to extend filesystem using network drive?

Tags: mount, filesystem, disk, lvm

I'm running very low free disk space on my file system.
Is it possible to extend file system size using network drive (using LVM or similar)
Preferably I would like to use Google drive (There is something called [Gdrive](https://askubuntu.com/q/161273/65926) to mount Google drive.)

Comment: The link you provided has nothing to do with Google drive, or even mounting network drives.  It simply tells how to use gparted to make an existing partition bigger on a local drive with unused space.

Comment: @MartyFried edited. It was Copy-Paste Error