# Alternative to Google Drive for Ubuntu

Tags: google-drive

I switched over to xubuntu, but one of the most important things that I really need/use seems to not be available for Linux. It's Google Drive, and the ones that I've tried such as Grive, just don't work properly (it syncs the first time you install it, but it doesn't sync again, not even if I do it manually).

So I wanted to ask if there's any good software out there for Ubuntu, that does work properly, that is a cloud based storage system with decent quota's, like 10 GB if possible.

Comment: I haven't had much problems with grive. This could be something else interfering. If this continues to be an issue, try the any of the answer, from the link karel gave you ^

Comment: For Ubuntu 12.10 or previous versions of Ubuntu, Grive is not in the default Ubuntu software sources. For Ubuntu 13.04 and onwards Grive is available in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: @blade19899 I basically get this 500 error, midway syncing - https://github.com/grive/grive/issues/118

Comment: refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available/675871#675871)

Answer (score 0):

U can try Gnome document but it's still in development phase. There is an app called Gdrive but I have never tried it so can't say how good that is.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Drive I use [Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/) on 3 machines (1 G drive account) it has worked flawlessly (and I have over 50gb synced using insync), it provides good configuration options to pick what you want to selectively sync.
I run a mixture of Ubuntu/Xubuntu and works fine on both desktops.

It is not free, but very worth the small cost.

[Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/) (5GB free) and [Drop box](https://www.dropbox.com/) (2GB free to start with, more with refferals) both have good support.