# How to write a shell script that synchronizes Google Drive to Linux OS?

Tags: sync, drive

Google drive is probably not the best choice for Linux and I think there are other free services compatible with Linux. I just wanted to know how painful it would be to write a script that would upload files from my Linux computer to Google Drive on start up and downloads files from Google Drive to my Linux computer to stay synchronized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried "[Grive](https://github.com/Grive/grive/)".

```
It simply downloads all the files in your Google Drive into the current directory.
after you make some changes to the local files, run grive again and it will upload
your changes back to your Google Drive. New files created locally or in Google Drive
will be uploaded or downloaded respectively. Deleted files will also be "removed".
```

also take a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available)