# Difference between Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.10 cloud storage

Tags: windows-8, cloud

What is the difference between Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.10 cloud storage?

Answer (score 2):

Both can use  [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/), [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/intl/en/drive/) (with a few [alternative clients](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available)), and a [few others](http://pclosmag.com/html/issues/201206/page07.html).

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses [Skydrive/Onedrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/). Ubuntu uses [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/).

They are both cloud storage. Skydrive integrates well with Microsoft products. Ubuntu One integrates well with Ubuntu. Both are free (to a point). They have differing storage sizes, and prices.

Comment: Ubuntu One is being discontinued....

Comment: @belacqua - [this sunday](https://one.ubuntu.com/services/shutdown/) (1st June).... :(