# External hard drive + Google drive (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04. Besides of default hard drive, I got also external hard drive on which I would like to install Google Drive. How can I do it?

I've read  [Is there a Google Drive client available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available)
but I don't know how to change the location (from internal hard drive to external)?

Result of:

```
sudo blkid; sudo parted -l
```

please find below. It's in polish ;)

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="98c61393-a17a-4c01-ab52-49b62a33a3ff" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="cefb2e69-872b-4832-9ef5-7576d5082af9" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="DATA" UUID="6A5AA8035AA7CA61" TYPE="ntfs"  

Model: ATA PLEXTOR PX-128M6 (scsi) 
Dysk /dev/sda: 128GB 
Rozmiar sektora (logiczny/fizyczny): 512B/512B Tablica partycji: msdos

Numer  Początek  Koniec  Rozmiar  Typ       System plików   Flaga  1  
1049kB    120GB   120GB    primary   ext4            ładowalna  2    
120GB     128GB   8479MB   extended  5     120GB     128GB   8479MB  
logical   linux-swap(v1)


Model: ASMT 2105 (scsi) Dysk /dev/sdb: 1000GB Rozmiar sektora
(logiczny/fizyczny): 512B/512B Tablica partycji: msdos

Numer  Początek  Koniec  Rozmiar  Typ      System plików  Flaga  1    
1049kB    1000GB  1000GB   primary  ntfs
```

result of

```
cat /etc/fstab

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.

# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).

#<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation 
UUID=98c61393-a17a-4c01-ab52-49b62a33a3ff /               ext4   errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation 
UUID=cefb2e69-872b-4832-9ef5-7576d5082af9 none            swap    sw   0       0 
UUID=6A5AA8035AA7CA61 /home/suzk/Drive ntfs-3g rw,exec,uid=,gid=,umask=0022 
UUID=6A5AA8035AA7CA61 /home/suzk/Drive ntfs-3g rw,exec,uid=,gid=,umask=0022 
UUID=6A5AA8035AA7CA61 /home/suzk/Drive ntfs-3g rw,exec,uid=,gid=,umask=0022
UUID=6A5AA8035AA7CA61 /home/suzk/Drive ntfs-3g rw,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022 
UUID=6A5AA8035AA7CA61 /home/suzk/Drive ntfs-3g rw,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022 
UUID=6
```

Comment: Post the output of `sudo blkid; sudo parted -l` after connecting the external disk. Please add it in the question.

Comment: @muru, I did it.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Here, run this command: `sudo sed -i '/UUID=6/d' /etc/fstab`. Then run the complete set of commands in my answer after that. I have update my answer to use the `~/Google Drive` path.

Comment: @muru but catalog Google Drive already exists. Should I remove it be removed before I run the command from your answer below? 2. What about privileges? Currently only root can create files on the external hdd

Comment: Yes, remove the files already in Google Drive. There were some garbage entries left in `/etc/fstab` from the error I had made, and removing them will fix the privileges problem - the sed command posted in the previous comment deletes all entries previously added for the external disk. After that, running the updated set of commands from the answer will mount the drive at `~/Google Drive` with the right privileges.

Comment: Are you sure? `Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.`

Comment: Did you run the `sudo umount /dev/sdb1` command?

Comment: Did it finish without an error?

Comment: Yes, without any errors. Currently I see this hdd 2: once as DATA and once as Drive.

Comment: Hey, small update: after restart it seams to work. I will give you a short notice when I will be sure :)

Comment: Unfortunately _it does not work_. Files uploaded from google drive occupies the **main hdd**. Because I have almost 100GB on GD, and main HDD is about 128 GB, all of these actions cause only a big mess...

Comment: Does the output of `mount` mention the Google Drive folder?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the Grive application uses `~/Google Drive` (i.e., something like `/home/suz/Drive`) as the sync folder. You can mount the external disk at `~/Drive` (or some folder within that folder). You will need to edit `/etc/fstab` for that, and make sure the external disk is connected whenever grive starts up.

You can mount your external drive to `~/Google Drive` using the following commands:

```
mkdir -p ~/Google\ Drive
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
sudo sed -i.bak '/6A5AA8035AA7CA61/d' /etc/fstab
sudo tee -a /etc/fstab <<EOF
UUID=6A5AA8035AA7CA61 $HOME/Google\040Drive ntfs-3g rw,exec,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -u),umask=0022
EOF
sudo mount ~/Google\ Drive
```

This will mount your external disk on `~/Google Drive` with correct permissions.

Comment: Hi, first of all thak you for helping me. When I run these commans I receive: 
`uid: nie znaleziono  gid: błędna opcja -- 'u' Try gid --help' for more information.` It means: 'uid: command not found' and 'gid: wrong option'

Comment: @suz Sorry, I made a typo. I had written `uid` and `gid` instead of `id`. Fixed,

Comment: Great. So after that I should just install Grive like it is described here: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/grive-open-source-google-drive-client.html
And the data will be stored on external drive. Correct?

Comment: @suz grive has changed a bit since that post, and I don't know if webupd8 have updated their PPA. You might want to check http://www.noobslab.com/2014/02/unofficial-google-drive-grive-tools.html

Comment: catalog Google Drive has been created in localization /home/Google drive/, not on the external drive... Plus, I cannot add any file to this external drive right now.

Comment: @suz `/home/Google Drive` or `/home/<username>/Google Drive `?

Comment: Sorry, it's /home/<username>/Google Drive. 
Catalog "Drive" currentlly is locked ('root' is the owner). When I restart the computer, I see information that disk cannot be mounted.

Comment: @suz Hmmm. Looks like the first try created an entry in fstab with the old command (the one with the error). Can you run the full set of commands again?

Comment: I did. After restart there is still information: An error occured while mounting /home/<user name>/Drive

Comment: @suz can you post your `fstab` (use `cat /etc/fstab`) in the question?

Comment: please find updated question.