# How to install Google Drive on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, google-drive

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, I tried to search for Google Drive on Ubuntu Software Center, but couldnot find it. Searched for answers in Askubuntu but all I found was ways to install [Google Drive on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available) which didn't worked for me.

Can anyone please give me some ideas?

---

Update: Don't know why they marked it as duplicate entry, as the link mentioned in question gives answer for Ubuntu 12.04, which as I see is two different things.

Comment: there isn't a native google drive client for linux yet by google. You might have to try out a 3rd party premium service [insync](https://www.insynchq.com/) or better wait for google to release one

Comment: It would be the smartest to also post the links to what did not work. Mind you: @karel answer still works for me (just tested it)

Comment: https://www.change.org/p/google-create-a-native-linux-google-drive-application

Comment: refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available/675871#675871)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**Updated 9/15/2015** Due to Google's changing API you might be having problem during installation of Grive. So the site I was referencing have also changed their tutorial for installing Grive2.

You can find new tutorial on this new link: [How to install Google Drive Grive2 on Ubuntu](http://justcode.me/ubuntu/install-google-drive-gdrive2-ubuntu/)

To install Grive2 in Ubuntu, Linux Mint and derivatives by using the main WebUpd8 PPA, use the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grive
```

Yes, It is true that there isn't a native google drive client for linux yet, so you couldn't get app on Software Center. And ways to install in 12.04 and 14.04 are somewhat different.

Old outdated reference Tutorial [How to install Google Drive on Ubuntu 14.04](https://youtu.be/PHWVPaV1MwQ)

Comment: I get this error :( grive-tools : Depends: grive (>= 0.3) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: @Saeid87 Follow the instructions here http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/grive-open-source-google-drive-client.html to get the later version of grive, then run the above commands.

Comment: I had to do apt-get install -f to get it working, but its working now Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

There is no official client of Google Drive for Linux based OSes, you can use grive/grive-tools though.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thefanclub/grive-tools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grive-tools
```

Then search for grive in the dash and follow the installers instructions.

Comment: I get the following error - 
Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app. This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In.