# no files in grive Google Drive Folder

Tags: google-drive, grive

I have installed grive . It creates google drive folder .
From gdrive menu bar when i click sync now it shows synchronizing and complete message .But no file syncs.My Auto sync is also on.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: using command line

Comment: which command?....

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/544646/how-to-install-google-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Try google-drive-ocamlfuse

Comment: Note if you find a question on this site and it is a duplicate of another question, you can generally find a better answer in the duplicate - in this case it is: [Is there a Google Drive client available?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grive is not very well maintained (last update was in 2013 I think), and google [deperecated the api it used](https://github.com/Grive/grive/issues/310#issuecomment-94571500) so it will not now work.

So for syncing Google Drive, you could try something else - for instance, [this fork of grive](https://github.com/vitalif/Grive2). You can install that as detailed [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/05/grive2-grive-fork-with-google-drive.html), by adding the PPA `ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` and installing the `grive` package, or installing the appropiate deb package from [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/g/grive2/),

You can also sync using the Chrome/Chromium browser, create a application shortcut for drive, then sync for offline use - see [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95710?hl=en-GB), [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2375012?hl=en) and [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375082?hl=en).

Google do provide [a native client for windows/mac](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2374989?hl=en) *(the Windows one may work under Wine, I haven't tried this yet)*, however there is no offical linux (or ubuntu) client. There is some demand for one - as shown by [this petition](https://www.change.org/p/google-create-a-native-linux-google-drive-application).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and also with bunch of other programs that were simply not available for Linux OS. I installed Windows to run off VirtualBox and this solved most of my issues

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't connected to the internet, you can still view and edit files that are stored on Google Drive, including:

- Google Docs
- Google Sheets
- Google Slides

#### Save and open Google Docs, Sheets and Slides offline

**Before you turn on offline access**

- You must be connected to the internet.
- You must use Google Chrome or Chromium web browser.
- Don't use private browsing.
- Install and turn on [Google Docs Offline Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs-offline/ghbmnnjooekpmoecnnnilnnbdlolhkhi).
- Make sure you have enough available space on your device to save your files.

**Open Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides offline**

1. Open Chrome or Chromium. Make sure you're [signed in](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277).
2. Go to [drive.google.com/drive/settings](https://drive.google.com/drive/settings).
3. Check the checkbox next to *Create, open, and edit your recent Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides files on this device while offline*.

**Save Google Docs, Sheets & Slides for offline use**

1. On your computer, go to [drive.google.com](https://drive.google.com/).
2. Right-click the Google Docs, Sheets, or Slides file you want to save offline.
3. Turn on *Available offline*.

To save multiple files offline, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> while you click other files.

<sub>**Source:** [Use Google Drive files offline - Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and managed to fix it.

If you open the google drive app from the icon on the taskbar and open preferences. I  then changed my google drive preferences to "Mirror Files". This creates a local copy of your files on your computer.

You may not want to create a local copy of all the files on your drive, but I assume the same fix will still work if only create a local copy of the files you need.