# How to set up Google Drive (grive) in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: google-drive, grive

I've been using Grive in Ubuntu 14.10, but after the upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10 the Google Drive app has been uninstalled automatically. How can I get it working again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Google Drive client available?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available)

Comment: There is also an updated answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/544646/how-to-install-google-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I have tried the above link. Still does not work.  Please offer other option

Comment: Please try to expand a little what you've been using exactly. And have you also tried new forks mentioned in comments, etc. (e.g. https://github.com/odeke-em/drive) as it seems the old grive no longers works because Google changed its API.

Comment: PETITION Google: https://www.change.org/p/google-create-a-native-linux-google-drive-application?recruiter=36432088&utm_source=share_petition&utm_medium=copylink

Answer (score 1):

You need to install it again, it happened to me too. Follow the steps on [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/05/grive2-grive-fork-with-google-drive.html) about installing, giving permission and syncing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grive
```

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal:

```
sudo su -c "nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/thefanclub*.list"
```

add line:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu vivid main
```

Then update package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And install Google Drive:

```
sudo apt-get install grive-tools
```