# Is "grive" available for Ubuntu 16.04 or has any new applications appeared for managing G drive files?

Tags: 16.04, filemanager, google-drive

I was wondering if Ubuntu 16.04 has a Gdrive application? I would like to manage my G drive files in a better way.

Comment: Not by default, but you can install it as given [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/544646/how-to-install-google-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Possible duplicate : [How to install Google Drive on Ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/544646/how-to-install-google-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: The PPA  linked as a dupe, has the packages for 16.04  but a small difference, it is called `grive2` and not just `grive`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Google Drive client available?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available)

Comment: I am using the one from nilarimogard, did you find a applet indicator substitute for it?

Answer (score 1):

InSync works like a charm, only it's 25$ a year. A couple of days ago it was 24h lifetime free licence. This may come again:

Download it here: https://www.insynchq.com/downloads

Install the deb. package.

To update your local file manager with Insync integration, use one of the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install insync-nautilus
sudo apt install insync-nemo
sudo apt install insync-caja
sudo apt install insync-thunar
sudo apt install insync-dolphin
```

If you are using Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit) and Insync doesn't start then run this command to fix it:

Terminal Commands:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/insync/libfontconfig.so.1 /usr/lib/insync/libfontconfig.so.1.old
```

Comment: I paid a one time fee for Insync.  Maybe it's changed?

Comment: Try to download and use it, should work.