# Grive will not sync on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sync, drive, google, grive

Yesterday I downloaded grive on my Ubuntu 14.04.

All my google drive files are now in my grive folder on my PC.
The problem is that I deleted some files in the grive folder and synced it (by writing "grive" in the terminal) but online-when I look in my google drive, these files are still there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grive sync error, possibly google API shift](http://askubuntu.com/questions/611801/grive-sync-error-possibly-google-api-shift)

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.  It worked for me.

http://www.webupd8.org/2015/05/grive2-grive-fork-with-google-drive.html

Answer (score 0):

Grive is no longer supported.

Google changed the Drive API to [a REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-sdk) and it no longer works.

There is a program that works - [OverGrive by The Fan Club](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive).