# Is it possible that Google Drive is in bundled in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive

Is it possible that Google Drive for ubuntu is included in Google Chrome?

I tried several times to install Google Drive unsuccessfully.

When I ran Google Chrome, the icons inherited from Windows still included the one for Google Drive, and I clicked on it without thinking. It ran, and has continued to run, normally ever since.

This leads me to wonder whether Drive is bundled in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive is a web application. Web applications are websites or webpages that can be accessed online and run as applications by themselves. Google Drive is not bundled with Google Chrome, and it is not necessary to install software locally in order to use Google Drive in a web browser.

Google Drive can also be accessed locally in Ubuntu. For instructions about how to access Google Drive locally in Ubuntu see: [Is there a Google Drive client available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available). Some of the answers to "Is there a Google Drive client available?" are obsolete, but at least [one of the answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available/320333#320333) has been updated recently, and it works in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive is built into the google.com web page - there shouldn't be anything to install. Google drive is an application just like gmail - no need to install anything.  You can access google drive from any web browser by going to google.com provided you are signed into your google account.