# How to do partial sync in grive (grive2)

Tags: sync, google-drive, grive

Grive2, which presents as grive version 0.4.0-1 seems to be working using the ppa from webupd8. Supposedly it can now do partial/selective sync. (see [Is there a Google Drive client available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available/320333#320333))

But something that is not revealed in the manpage is how to do this, other than using the -s switch and manually syncing individual folders. I remember reading about a .exclude file where supposedly you list the files you want ignored in a sync, but this is cumbersome to maintain, especially if you have a Google Drive as big as mine.

Does anyone know how to format .exclude, and if it can use wildcards, e.g. something like this:

```
\# Exclude the following:
/My Drive/Photos/big/*
./Google Photos/*.jpg
```

*Edit:* Just got a reply from the developer on GitHub, who says there is no .exclude file, but he is working on something like this. Now I am doubly confused because I don't know where I read about it, but I know I'm not dreaming!

Comment: @DavidFoerster  Voting to keep open as it appears that the feature does exist now although did not when the question was asked.

Answer (score 3):

Also interested & accidentally found a workaround, steps:

1. install grive2
2. authenticate and start full sync by `grive -a` in the `~/grive` folder
3. wait till files in Google Drive root folder will be downloaded and break it when syncing first subfolder
4. create new subfolder such as `~/grive/myfiles` and put some files here
5. start single folder sync by `grive -s ~/grive/myfiles`
6. repeat step 5 when you want to sync changes in `myfiles` folder

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that starting a full sync is required as mentioned by @mschanya. It appears that since Grive2 v0.4.0 partial sync is supported at the folder level with the command `grive -s subdir`

It also seems that since Grive2 v0.4.2 there is an option to exclude files by perl regexp with the switch --ignore arg  {Perl RegExp to ignore files (matched against relative paths, remembered for next runs)}.

Github address is [here](https://github.com/vitalif/grive2/)

Source:http://yourcmc.ru/wiki/Grive2#Syncs