# Can grive2 sync to a google drive directory?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, server, grive

I'm syncing my server backups to google drive every night via a CRON job. But grive just drops the backups in my google drives root directory.

I'd like to create a directory in google drive called "webserver_backups" and have grive sync to that instead of the google drive root directory. Is this possible?

Comment: This link may help : https://askubuntu.com/a/809233/435361

Comment: nope. That question is what made me ask this one. it's not clear in the answer what the output in google drive will be. Thanks though. Additionally, I tried to sync a folder, and it didn't create the folder in G-Drive as expected. Instead it put everything inside the folder into the root directory of my G-Drive.