# How to install google drive on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, drive, google

Can anyone tell me how to install google drive in Ubuntu 15.10?

Comment: Probably has it's answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available

Comment: "google drive" : There is no install. just "login" here  https://drive.google.com/drive/

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i found on the net :

#### 1. Install Grive Tools PPA :

Open a the terminal and run :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thefanclub/grive-tools
sudo apt-get update
```

#### 2. Install Grive :

You may need to Amend the Grive-Tools Repo :

```
sudo su -c "nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/thefanclub*.list"
```

Change the `wily` at the end of line in `vivid` :

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu vivid main
```

After that do the update :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And finally Install Grive Tools for Ubuntu :

```
sudo apt-get install grive-tools
```

Sources :

[Linux Ubuntu/Mint How-to Install Grive Tools PPA](http://paperiniktips.sviluppo-siti-web.com/linux-ubuntu-how-to-install-grive-tools-ppa/)

[How-to QuickStart with Google Drive on Ubuntu 15.10 Wily 32-64bit Linux+GNU](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/10/15/how-to-quickstart-with-google-drive-on-ubuntu-15-10-wily-32-64bit-linuxgnu/)

For more informations (Quick-Start):

[Quick-Start with Google Drive on Linux](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/05/06/linux-google-drive-quick-start-with-grive-tools-easy-visual-guide/)

Comment: The developers of grive tools told me that they are not mantaining it anymore, now they offer their own client called overGrive, which costs $5.

Comment: The above procedure doesn't not work.Show this message:>W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend simply going to https://drive.google.com/drive/ - It's the best way to reach Google Drive.