# Add google to Online Acount

Tags: kubuntu, 17.04, google-drive

I've just installed Kubuntu 17.04,

I'd like to have access to my Google Doc and files.

when I want to add my Google account to *Online Account*, I receive the following error:

> There was an error while trying to process the request:
>   userActionFinished error: 2

I also installed another software with the same name (online account), and it generates this error:

> Please authorise Ubuntu to access to your Google account

What should I do?

Comment: Regarding Google Drive, you may want to read [Is there a Google Drive client available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/161273/301745)

Comment: This might be a known bug. See [kde-telepathy, impossible to connect to gmail accounts](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/meta-kde-telepathy/+bug/1070873)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, It seems to be buggy now and unfortunately there's no official Google Drive Client for Linux.

Opensuse has [Kio-Drive](https://software.opensuse.org/package/kio-gdrive) which works really good and useful, and The biggest feature in GNOME 3.18 is native Google Drive integration.Sad it's not yet for KDE.

However, I can propose you some other workaround which me personally use it to synch my files. Dropbox is one of them, and you can sync your Google drive files with it via some plugins such as [CloudHQ](https://www.cloudhq.net/google_apps). With this method you can have all of your Google Drive files synced back and forth with your Dropbox.

Also I'd like to mention other methods like OverGrive and InSync which cost money ($5 ~ $30), which I personally didn't like them.

Comment: Insync works well for me, although there's been kind of a flame war over their pricing policies recently.

Comment: Yes indeed, 
But it's pricey, :|

Answer (score 2):

I use overgrive with kubuntu and it works fabulous. It certainly isnt an official google drive client but gets the job done.