# Free Google Drive Client to Sync files/folders for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, sync, cloud, google-drive

I want to sync my files on the Google Drive cloud and use them offline for free.

I have many types of files on Google Drive.

Comment: install google chrome

Comment: @ravery Will it sync everything? I have 250Gb on the cloud among many types of files.

Comment: it syncs google drive. how did you get them there if not with chrome?

Comment: @ravery I have it on Windows.

Comment: @ravery, Am I able to see those files on nautilus?

Comment: you have chrome on windows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66101/discussion-between-vitor-abella-and-ravery).

Comment: [Google Drive integration in GNOME 3.18 and newer (Ubuntu 16.10 and later)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available/320333#320333) *GNOME 3.18 and newer (which is installed by default in Ubuntu 17.10) has native desktop integration that will let you easily browse, manage, open, upload, and download your files. Just add your Google account in GNOME's online accounts application to get started.*

Answer (score 2):

A very indirect alternative:

1. Install google drive on a windows guest/virtual os (I used virtualbox).
2. Install SyncToy to sync files between your Ubuntu system (shared folder) and google drive folder on windows system.

Viola. You just have to run SyncToy whenever you would like to sync your files on your Ubuntu filesystem with google drive.

---

UPDATE: I recently found that [`GoodSync`](https://www.goodsync.com/) is a good alternative to Microsoft's `SyncToy`.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive

Command line. Works like a charm.

Comment: Hmm, this isnt working for me, says "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app..This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In." after I click on the generated auth link on CLI which opens in the browser.

Comment: Still not working