# Google Drive Sync

Tags: 18.04, google-drive

I would like to sync my files with Drive as described in the [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/320333/186134).

Following those steps, I always get the message: "Login expired. Log in to activate account" just after a successful login into Google. The message is displayed in the dialogue where one can normally choose the functions to be synced (calendar, files...)

[image: Sync dialogue with error]

Comment: Do you have 2 factor authentication enabled?

Comment: I deleted the Ubuntu One Account which was connected, too. Then I restarted the machine what solved the issue.

Comment: The Google drive tool is quite slow and pretty much unusable.