# How do I install Google's "Drive File Stream"?

Tags: cloud, file-sharing, google, google-drive

I was wondering if it is possible to install **[Google Drive File Stream](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7491144?hl=en)** on Ubuntu 18.04. I recently bought G-Suite and want to use it in Ubuntu. I have tried "**[Is there a Google Drive client available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available/320333#320333)**", which succeeded in getting me access to my Google Drive, but I really (if possible) need access to Google Photos and Team Drives.

Can someone please show me how this is done? (assuming it can be done)