# How to make Google Drive folder available offline?

Tags: 18.04, offline, google-drive

I'm using Google Drive, mounting it automatically after logged in in [online account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdpzJ.png), but I've read that Google Drive mounted doesn't keep a offline copy of the drive so any access take a long time. Is there a way to force Google Drive to be cache offline?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way (imo) for 20.04 is to use [google-drive-ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse).
I don't know whether it is compatible with 18.04 or 20.1 but it's the best way for 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

Because of a change of security policy from Google, Nextcloud 13 and ownCloud have removed support for Google Drive external storage, but accessing Google Docs files offline is supported by the Google Docs Offline Chrome extension offered by google.com. After installing the Google Docs Offline Chrome extension return to Google Drive and navigate to gear icon -> *Settings* -> *Offline*, and enable *Create, open and edit your recent Google Docs, Sheets and Slides files while offline*.

---

#### Access Google Docs files offline

To turn on offline access:

- You must be connected to the Internet.
- Use the [Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome) browser.
- Don't use incognito mode.
- Install and enable [Google Docs Offline Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs-offline/ghbmnnjooekpmoecnnnilnnbdlolhkhi).
- Make sure you have enough free space on your device to save your files.

<sup>**Source:** [Use Google Drive files offline – Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012)</sup>

Comment: This only works for google docs files type, not all google drive files. Maybe you should do a small edit clarifying since the question asks about all types of google drive files.

Answer (score 0):

You may use https://www.insynchq.com/downloads
It has 15 days trials and then 30$ one time, if you are ok with not syncing team drives.

From free apps - there is https://github.com/gdrive-org/gdrive

--

Comprehensive answer here:
[Is there a Google Drive client available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available/320333#320333)