# Open Drive stuck on getting files info

Tags: google-drive

As Google Drive using GNOME Online accounts takes a [very long time](https://askubuntu.com/q/1089495/719469) to load my files, I installed the best free alternative I thought that was available, i.e. Open Drive using `sudo snap install odrive-unofficial`. However when I click on <kbd>Synchronize</kbd> on the GUI, it gets stuck on

> Getting files info...

On running the app from terminal with the command `odrive-unofficial` it shows the following:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
/snap/odrive-unofficial/2/resources/app.asar/public
app started on port 16409
remote change false false
local change false false
Updating account info
Updating tray icon, connected:  true syncing:  false
Initial scan complete. Ready for changes
Saving account to db
Saved account!
Get home page
Number of accounts 1
GET / 302 6.670 ms - 62
GET /settings 304 10.868 ms - -
GET /javascript/preload.js 200 7.304 ms - 274
GET /javascript/tether.min.js 200 5.697 ms - 25021
GET /javascript/settings.js 200 5.448 ms - 1623
GET /javascript/jquery.min.js 200 5.995 ms - 86927
GET /stylesheets/styles.css 200 6.250 ms - 173172
GET /javascript/frontend.js 200 5.904 ms - 200952
GET /files/af7ae505a9eed503f8b8e6982036873e.woff2 200 1.043 ms - 77160
Saving account to db
Saved account!
syncing true
Updated syncing status
Updating tray icon, connected:  true syncing:  true
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
Connection error received, waiting 2 seconds and retrying
Files list done!
Files list done!
Files list done!
```

This process does not seem to stop. I do not know whether this process is recurring or making progress. Is there any way I can view the progress, or is there any other alternative? (My current Google Drive has 4.5GB of used storage space)

Answer (score 1):

Though I can't speak directly, to your problem with Open Drive, I can offer an alternative for syncing files on Linux systems.

For syncing cloud services that don't supply a Linux syncing client, I recommend `rclone`. It is [very well documented](https://rclone.org/) for a number of services, though I've only used it for Google Drive and Box. It doesn't offer a continuous synchronization option, but one could be constructed using `crontab`. There is no GUI, so that may be a drawback for your particular use-case.

Comment: Lol, no GUI is a huge drawback in my case

Comment: Unless you can identify that the behavior of Open Drive is a Ubuntu specific issue, I think this question would be better suited for the [Issues Page](https://github.com/liberodark/ODrive/issues) on the Open Drive GitHub page. They will be better equipped to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior. You just have to **wait more**.

*Open Drive* is not as fast as *Backup and Sync* from Google. It took my client many hours to finally start downloading files.