# Nautilus integration with Google Drive, different behaviour between 18.04.3 LTS and 20.04 (Daily Build)

Tags: nautilus, online-accounts, google-drive

I've been using ubuntu 18.04 since it's release and I've always had problems using the integrated Google Drive feature.

It takes a LONG time to load the files from my Google account, exactly like the problem reported in this question: [Google Drive takes a very long time to open with GNOME Online Accounts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089495/google-drive-takes-a-very-long-time-to-open-with-gnome-online-accounts)

Recently, I downloaded the 20.04 daily build image to test, and voilà! It works like a charm!

What happened? It's a fix in nautilus itself, or a gnome fix? Is there any way to reproduce the same behaviour on 18.04?

Edit: The same thing is observed on 19.04. Loading times are reasonable.

Comment: You may not get too many answers on this one since questions about unreleased versions (such as 20.04) are considered off-topic: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Well, I've just tested 19.04 and it works too, as in 20.04. I'm narrowing the problem step by step.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For 20.04 questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is April 23rd, 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).  You also mention Ubuntu 19.04 which  is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looking a bit further I found the answer, not in an ubuntu forum per say, but in a Linux Mint one. Mint uses Nero as a file manager which is a fork of Nautilus. The issue is discussed here: [Mint 19 Cinnamon (Nemo): Google drive loading takes a huge amount of time](https://github.com/linuxmint/linuxmint/issues/39#issuecomment-548584898).

In short, there was a huge re-work done to the gvfs library between 18.10 and 19.04 that fixed the issue. The fix was merged in version 1.39, but the 18.04.3 LTS incorporates version 1.36. There is currently no backport for a newer version, and probably no easy fix for the moment...

Comment: Well done!  I'd have preferred a Ubuntu ref (ie. fix by Ubuntu GNOME dev Jeremy Bicha https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/1.39.90-1) rather then the Mint ref talking about it... but well done.