# Why is Nautilus so slow in copying files to Google Drive?

Tags: nautilus, sync, google-drive

I was trying to copy a directory from a local drive to Google Drive using Nautilus. But Nautilus is showing that it needs 596,523 hours. Also, there no apparent progress in copying. When I used Google Drive itself (folder upload), it is suggesting a time something like 24 hours.

Why is there such a substantial difference in the time required? And what can be done to solve the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Drive takes a very long time to open with GNOME Online Accounts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089495/google-drive-takes-a-very-long-time-to-open-with-gnome-online-accounts)

Comment: @User24601 It does and it does not. Based on the question you mentioned, I am in the process of devising a complete solution for me. I will try to write an answer if I am successful. I will need some time before that.

Comment: I think it's a case of poor integration of Google Drive with Ubuntu/Linux rather than the fault of Nautilus tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question based on the comments from the kind
readers. Using the directions in [the pages pointed to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089495/google-drive-takes-a-very-long-time-to-open-with-gnome-online-accounts) plus a few others, I have
devised a framework that is working fine after a few tweaks.

**The Framework Summary**

- Mount your Google Drive on Linux with `google-drive-ocamlfuse`.
- Use `rsync` to copy files and directories.

**Framework Setup Details**

- Install and setup `google-drive-ocamlfuse`. In a terminal window, run,

  > ```
  > sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa &&\ 
  > sudo apt update && sudo apt install google-drive-ocamlfuse
  > ```

.

- Authorize `google-drive-ocamlfuse` so it will have access to your Google
  account. In the terminal window and issue the command
  `google-drive-ocamlfuse`. This command will open a browser window that
  will either prompt you to log into your Google account or if you're
  already logged in, ask you to allow `google-drive-ocamlfuse` access to
  your Google account. If you've not logged in, do so and then click
  Allow. The next window will ask you to grant permission for both
  gdfuse and OAuth2 Endpoint to access your Google account. Click Allow
  again. The next browser screen will inform you to wait until the
  authorization tokens have downloaded. When your terminal prompt
  returns with the message, “Access token retrieved correctly”, you know the tokens have been downloaded, and you're ready
  to mount.
- Mount your Google Drive.  Create a directory (e.g. google-drive) to serve
  as the mount point (in subsequent discussions we are going to term
  this as either the source or destination directory, whichever
  applicable for you). From the terminal, issue the command,`mkdir ~/google-drive`, to create a new directory in your home directory. Issue
  the command `google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/google-drive` to mount your Google
  Drive to the google-drive directory.
- At this point, you should see your Google Drive files/directories populate
  in the google-drive directory. You can work with Google Drive as if it
  were a local directory system.
- When you want to unmount the google-drive directory, issue the command
  `fusermount -u ~/google-drive`.

More on the previous steps can be found [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-mount-your-google-drive-on-linux-with-google-drive-ocamlfuse/).

- Now you can start copying your files and directories using any GUI or
  command line methodology you like. But I found rsync to be especially
  suited for the purpose. I found the following command suitable (and
  optimized) for my case.

> ```
> rsync -uvrt --progress --human-readable <source directory/>\
> <destination directory/>
> ```

**A Few Words about rsync**

rsync is a fast and extraordinarily versatile file copying tool.  It
can copy locally, to/from another host over any remote shell, or
to/from a remote rsync daemon. One of the important features of rsync is that it works on “delta transfer algorithm”, which means it will only sync or copy the changes from source to the destination instead of copying the whole file which ultimately reduce the amount of data sent over the network. Please see the man page for rsync or [this page](https://www.marksanborn.net/howto/use-rsync-for-daily-weekly-and-full-monthly-backups/) for
details.

rsync can be stopped (terminated) anytime and rsync will resume from
that point at the next invocation. Please see [this question (and answers)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/how-can-i-pause-resume-rsync) for other helpful hints.