# Gnome Online Accounts very slow with Google Drive

Tags: gnome, 23.10, online-accounts, google-drive

I am using Ubuntu 23.10 and did the whole process of configuring my Google Account with Gnome via the Online Account section in the settings. After doing so, and making sure only files is enabled as seen here:

[image]

Copying a local folder to Google Driver is painfully slow. Like VERY SLOW as seen here:

[image]

For reference, my speed right now:

[image]

I do not want to use an alternative as seen here (which many of those are gone now): [Google Drive takes a very long time to open with GNOME Online Accounts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089495/google-drive-takes-a-very-long-time-to-open-with-gnome-online-accounts)

Do note that the issue here is speed, not connecting google to gnome (That part worked  flawlessly).

Comment: I can't really answer your question and I know you said  you don't want "those" alternatives but I dropped the Gnome/Google link years ago and never looked back. Not necessarily for speed reasons but using `google-drive-ocamlfuse` you can setup your Google Drive to act just like any other local or network drive. Seems to fully support `rsync`too. Free & open source, see: https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse

Comment: Thank you a lot @codlord but for the specific scenario I am in, we can not use that one. The closest way is the gnome online account but we were not aware of the speed issue.