# Is it secure to connect a google account with online accounts of GNOME?

Tags: gnome, security, online-accounts, google-drive

I am new to Ubuntu. I was trying to connect my Google Drive account with Ubuntu and saw this related [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available/320333#320333). When I try to synchronize gnome with the google account it asks for access to basically everything on my google account.

I saw this related [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/5v0ulb/security_of_connecting_google_to_gnome/?sort=new) on Reddit, but I am still concerned.

**My questions are:** is it secure to give gnome access (read, edit, create, delete) to all my files, emails, calendar, photos, etc? Should I trust gnome?

Comment: This is also a very interesting related article about the benefits of signing in with your Google Account in Ubuntu: [FossLinux.com: How to integrate your Google account into GNOME shell](https://www.fosslinux.com/58548/integrate-google-account-into-gnome-shell.htm). It allows you to access your Google Drive in your Ubuntu file manager, apparently!

Answer (score 4):

I would say so with the proviso that you should invoke [2 step verification on](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/) on your Google account.

I have been using my Google account with Ubuntu for some time and have not had any issues of concern.

If security still concerns you, you can also install ClamTK from the Ubuntu Software Center for an additional layer of security/peace of mind.

Comment: I have 2 step verification on my google account. My security concern raised because gnome asked permission for too many stuff, and I am new to Ubuntu. Have you synchronised everything? Is there a way to limit gnome access to some features, e.g., e-mail?

Comment: Yes. Go to Online Accounts and select Google (the one at the top you have already selected). That gives you a list of items in your Google Account you have given permissions to and deselect those you do not wish permission to be given to.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using that feature for a couple of Months now and it needs the read, edit, create and delete permissions because it allows you to access your Google Drive inside the File Manager. If you wouldn't give those permissions you could for example not open the files inside your Drive.