# Google account/google shared drive: cannot open libreoffice files clicking on files

Tags: libreoffice, 22.04, online-accounts, google-drive

I have logged in to my google account in "online accounts" and I have seen my files there both in a shared drive and in my personal drive. I can copy them to "Documents" and open them from there with Libreoffice, but if I click on them directly on Google drive:

On the shared drive, Libreoffice seems to open but then in the end does not

On the personal one LO does not open at all.

I also noticed that from time to time, going back to the shared drive I get the message "This location could not be displayed: Sorry could not display all the contents of "Shared drives": The connection is closed. This is temporary though. Now it shows correctly again.

I also tried to open Libreoffice first and then open the personal or shared drives from there, but in the open window only the documents folder is displayed. So I tried to click on Manage Services/Servers and add Google Drive inserting my email and credentials, but I get an error pop up message: "The specified device is invalid".

I am pretty new to Ubuntu and would like to be able to be able to work on these files as if they were in my file system.

Any suggestions?

I am running V. 22.04. 1 LTS on a MacBook Pro mid 2012

Comment: It is what it is. Files must be downloaded because what you see is NOT a sync folder but a listing of file available in the cloud.

Comment: Thanks @ChanganAuto, do you know, or does anybody know how I can sync?

Comment: Unlike so many other cloud service, Google Drive does not provide a native Linux sync client. There are a few unofficial ones, some free, some payed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Google Drive client available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available)

Comment: @ChanganAuto, great! Do you know where I can find a list of the unofficial clients, or can you recommend a free one?